# IP from sending email server is different than from email-domain

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I have my own domain for my business. In my host I have configured that the emails are forwarded to my outlook account.

In my outlook account I have configured the emails from my own domain as account alias to send and receive emails.

I am using so email with my own domain in outlook.com.

So far it was worked fine, but recently I have experienced in many occasions that nobody is replying to my answer on their requests. I had also a customer from uk who was sending me emails but it I did not receive it, nor it was in my spam folder. And I know one occassion, where the customer said he never did receive my response to their request. I sent it again with my outlook.com email, and then it did go to the customer. :(

I am wondering, since the server IP, which is sending my email (outlook.com) is different from my emails name (my domain) could it be that my email is beeing filtered as spam?

I already checked, if my domain is blacklisted, but it was not the case.

I am now worrying, that lot of my emails are not going through to the customers. Would it be better to install a client like outlook or thunderbird on my pc and configure the account directly to my domains account? Or does this not make a difference?

Pls note, none of my customers has told me, that my email was in spam-folder, but I am worrying that they just vanish in the wide internet. Since my business in dependend on that email communication, I am really worried. I searched already in the internet about a good explanation on that matter, but I found none.

I would be really pleased if someone could help me to get clarification on that matter

Comment: Are you using [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)? (Check [here](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html).)

Comment: As for your title edit: what "email domain" IP address are you referring to? DNS MX records for *receiving* email are unrelated to any problems when sending. (And also WWW settings such as DNS A and AAAA records are unrelated.)

Comment: @Arjan You have answered your own question. With SPF, the IP and MX entry can be important for outgoing email.

Comment: @Paul, we don't know if the OP is using SPF, as the question lacks any info about that. And the OP is also not responding to these comments. Fail.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! I checked, my domain is not using SPF: _No valid SPF record found of either type TXT or type SPF._ By "email domain" I meant my own domain, which I am using as sending adress. But the email itself is sent from outlook.com. Hope this gives more information

Comment: @Owl Not using SPF means that you are not telling receiving servers what is a valid source for emails from your domain. Some servers may consider outlook.com IP addresses as spammy, but it isn't likely.  If servers at your customer premises are rejecting the emails, they will have logs showing why, so I think pick a friendly one and see what is going on.  I'd also consider creating an SPF and being explicit about outlook.com as a source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789058%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Comment: ok thank you so much, I would upvote if I could! So would it be better to use SPF, but I'd need another hosting. But generally said, it should not be such a big problem using different IPs as sending adress, and the IP adress where the email is actually coming from?